# Is there a way to quickly switch between silent and vibrate? (not vibrate and ring + vibrate, or silent and ring)

Tags: ringtone, volume, vibration

I only ever want my phone on one of two settings:

- Completely silent at night, during classes, and during meetings
- Vibrate during the rest of the day

I never want it to ring, ever.

When I change the volume, a nice toggle option appears in the upper-right corner of my phone. However, it only seems to have these options:

- When vibrate is on, it toggles between "vibrate" and "ring + vibrate".
- When vibrate is off, it toggles between "silent" and "ring".

Is there any way to make this button toggle between "silent" and "vibrate"?

Comment: +10 from me. I'm really stumped by this too. Any app to the rescue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is now possible in Windows Phone 8.1, as the Volume Bar now has an interactive slider for ringer volume and a separate toggle for vibrate:

[image]

To open the Volume Bar, press either of the volume keys as usual, then expand it by tapping the chevron. Reduce ringer volume to 0 with the volume keys or by dragging the slider, and now you can toggle between vibrate and silent by tapping on the icon at the bottom.

For more information on the new Volume Bar, see the following article by Paul Thurrott:
[Windows Phone 8.1 Tip: Master the New Custom Volume Settings](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-81-tip-master-new-custom-volume-settings)

Comment: Protip: You can also tap the icons in front of each slider to quickly mute/unmute the respective volume.

Answer (score 0):

It appears [this app](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appId=f347a36b-80c0-430f-8631-e55046ee5a2a) might be of use - but not exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm afraid that searching for an app that solves this kind of needs is pointless, since Windows Phone doesn't allow you to access low-level API. Just noticing it for those who might want to ask for apps that are allowing things mentioned above.

Answer (score -5):

yes you can change your profile to only ring 
no vibrate

just go to setting than in sounds enables and disable vibrate

press volume button and toggle your profile enjoy..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as I described in my original question, I'm aware that you can toggle vibration in the settings menu. I'm looking for a way to *quickly* do it, like you can for the ringer.